# Using React.lazy gives Element type is invalid

Tags: reactjs

So I have isolated the issue to this import:

```
const SelectRecipients = React.lazy(() => 
    import('../components/SelectRecipients'))
```

I get the following error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

I thought maybe it was an issue with the component itself and tried making a test component as follows:

```
import React from 'react'
export default () => {
return(<div>Hi</div)}
```

and then imported it instead of `SelectRecipients` and still got the error

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kkokwy4lqo)

Comment: This is working fine in CodeSandBox

Answer (score 0):

For me, issue was having another `index.js` in the path, and my new component's codes was in `index.jsx`. This is because the `index.js` has higher priority when resolving imports.